# why my fixed size array queue compile by gcc with -O2 hang?

Tags: c++, gcc, queue

in linux, it works well without optimize,but in -O1,-O2 ,test code will hang when **m_head = m_volumn**

in windows, ether in debug or release mode works well.

It makes me very confused.

queue:

```
#define rmb() asm volatile("lfence":::"memory")
#define wmb() asm volatile("sfence" ::: "memory")

template <typename T>
class fixedQueue
{
private:
    T* m_queue;
    uint32_t m_volumn;
    uint32_t m_mask;
    uint32_t m_head;
    uint32_t m_tail;
    static uint32_t calVolumn(uint32_t size)
    {
        uint32_t s = 1;
        while ((s <<= 1) < size);
        return s;
    }
    inline uint32_t nextPos(uint32_t pos)
    {
        return (pos + 1) & m_mask;
    }
    inline bool isEndPos(uint32_t pos)
    {
        return nextPos(pos) == m_tail
    }
public:
    fixedQueue(int size = 256) :m_volumn(calVolumn(size)), m_mask(m_volumn - 1), m_head(0), m_tail(0)
    {
        m_queue = new T[m_volumn];
    }
    inline bool full()
    {
        return isEndPos(m_head);
    }
    inline bool empty()
    {
        return m_head == m_tail;
    }
    inline bool push(T& v)
    {
        uint32_t next = nextPos(m_head);
        if (next == m_tail)
            return false;
        m_queue[next] = v;
        wmb();
        m_head = next;
        return true;
    }
    inline bool pop(T& v)
    {
        if (empty())
            return false;
        uint32_t next = nextPos(m_tail);
        v = m_queue[next];
        wmb();
        m_tail = next;
        return true;
    }
}
```

test code:

```
int testSingleThreadPopPush()
{
        fixedQueue<int> q(1024);
        std::thread t1([&]() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                        while (!q.push(i));
                });
        std::thread t2([&]() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
                        int v;
                        while (!q.pop(v));
                        assert(v == i);
                }});
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        return 0;
}
```

gdb info:
push thread:

```
#0  fixedQueue<int>::push (v=<synthetic pointer>: 1023, this=0x7fffffffd470) at util/fixedQueue.h:48
#1  <lambda()>::operator() (__closure=0x617ec8) at util/unittest/testFixedQueue.cpp:11
#2  std::__invoke_impl<void, testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > (__f=...) at 
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/invoke.h:60
#3  std::__invoke<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > (__fn=...) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/invoke.h:95
#4  std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > >::_M_invoke<0> (this=0x617ec8) at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:244
#5  std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > >::operator() (this=0x617ec8) at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:253
#6  std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > > >::_M_run(void) (this=0x617ec0) at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:196
#7  0x00007ffff78e1b73 in execute_native_thread_routine () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff7bbc2de in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff6fbee83 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) p next
$1 = 0
(gdb) p m_tail
$2 = 1023
(gdb) p m_head
$3 = 1023
```

pop thread:

```
#0  fixedQueue<int>::pop (v=<synthetic pointer>: <optimized out>, this=0x7fffffffd470) at util/fixedQueue.h:58
#1  <lambda()>::operator() (__closure=0x618018) at util/unittest/testFixedQueue.cpp:16
#2  std::__invoke_impl<void, testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > (__f=...) at 
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/invoke.h:60
#3  std::__invoke<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > (__fn=...) at /usr/include/c++/8/bits/invoke.h:95

#4  std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > >::_M_invoke<0> (this=0x618018) at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:244

#5  std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > >::operator() (this=0x618018) at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:253
#6  std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > > >::_M_run(void) (this=0x618010) at /usr/include/c++/8/thread:196
#7  0x00007ffff78e1b73 in execute_native_thread_routine () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x00007ffff7bbc2de in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#9  0x00007ffff6fbee83 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

plateform:

centos 8

gcc version:

gcc version 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5) (GCC)

Answer (score 0):

Dump of assembler code for function

```
   0x0000000000401850 <+0>: xor    %edx,%edx
   0x0000000000401852 <+2>: mov    0x8(%rdi),%rcx
   0x0000000000401856 <+6>: mov    0x10(%rcx),%esi
   0x0000000000401859 <+9>: mov    0x14(%rcx),%eax
   0x000000000040185c <+12>:    cmp    %eax,%esi
=> 0x000000000040185e <+14>:    je     0x40185c <std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > > >::_M_run(void)+12>
   0x0000000000401860 <+16>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000401863 <+19>:    mov    (%rcx),%rsi
   0x0000000000401866 <+22>:    and    0xc(%rcx),%eax
   0x0000000000401869 <+25>:    mov    %eax,%r8d
   0x000000000040186c <+28>:    mov    (%rsi,%r8,4),%esi
   0x0000000000401870 <+32>:    sfence 
   0x0000000000401873 <+35>:    mov    %eax,0x14(%rcx)
   0x0000000000401876 <+38>:    cmp    %edx,%esi
   0x0000000000401878 <+40>:    jne    0x401886 <std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > > >::_M_run(void)+54>
   0x000000000040187a <+42>:    add    $0x1,%edx
   0x000000000040187d <+45>:    cmp    $0xf4240,%edx
   0x0000000000401883 <+51>:    jne    0x401852 <std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > > >::_M_run(void)+2>
   0x0000000000401885 <+53>:    retq   
   0x0000000000401886 <+54>:    push   %rax
   0x0000000000401887 <+55>:    mov    $0x403300,%ecx
   0x000000000040188c <+60>:    mov    $0x11,%edx
   0x0000000000401891 <+65>:    mov    $0x402d90,%esi
   0x0000000000401896 <+70>:    mov    $0x402dcb,%edi
   0x000000000040189b <+75>:    callq  0x4010e0 <__assert_fail@plt>
```

problem is in here

```
   0x000000000040185c <+12>:    cmp    %eax,%esi
=> 0x000000000040185e <+14>:    je     0x40185c <std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<testSingleThreadPopPush()::<lambda()> > > >::_M_run(void)+12>
```

it read m_head and m_tail to eax and esi,then compare eax and esi,if equal, retry compare eax and esi without reload m_head and m_tail to register. so if m_head = m_tail ,then it will go to an endless loop.

Comment: so change [ uint32_t m_head;uint32_t m_tail; ] to [  volatile  uint32_t m_head;volatile uint32_t m_tail;],now all is ok